# Oracle Apex 5.1.1 Interactive Report with PL/SQL

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

How do I can to create an **interactive report** with **PL/SQL** in **Apex 5.1.1**?

It's important that work in **Apex 5.1.1**

The IR have a PL/SQL with **Dynamic Parameters** that I want change the query **before submit** with values of parameters that user can select

Comment: What does that mean, "create IR with PL/SQL"?

Comment: @Littlefoot The IR has a PL/SQL with Dynamic Parameters that I want change query with values of parameters that user can select.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Could you, please, edit the question and post what it looks like? Doesn't matter if it doesn't work, I'd like to see the *illustration* of the question. Code you wrote, as well as screenshot would be nice.

Comment: @Littlefoot Unfortunately I can't upload any pictures til post 50 in stack. by the way, I have a query and want to change it before page submit. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Aha, that would be a function (i.e. *PL/SQL* program unit) that returns query which is used as a source for the interactive report? If so, let it accept parameters which will be used to compose the SELECT statement. Depending on what you pass, you'll get appropriate SELECT.

I'd suggest you to move the function into the database (i.e. so that it is a *stored* function). Doing so, you'll be able to test it in a simple manner than if it was in Apex.

Comment: I don't know what you mean . But I know I can do this with function. Is the better way for this?

In the Apex 18 there is a IR with PL/SQL function body return SQL query but I can't find it in Apex 5.1.1..

Comment: I've just checked it. In Apex 5.1, there's only a **Classic report** that can be based on a function that returns query. In Apex 18.2, Interactive report can also be based on a function, but that's not an option for Apex 5.1. It means that you have two options: switch to a classic report, or upgrade to 18.2.

Comment: Can I use Classic Report for PL/SQL function body return SQL query ? Can you show me with image please?

Comment: Yes, you can. When creating a classic report, its **Identification** property contains the "Title", "Type" which can be "Classic report" or "**Classic report (based on function)**" (which is what you want). I can't attach the image; I'm at work and we don't have access to such sites, sorry.